# Problems while inserting df values with python into Oracle db

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, list, dataframe

I am having troubles when trying to insert data from a df into an Oracle database table, this is the error:  DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

These are the steps I did:

This is the dataframe I have imported from yfinance package and elaborated in order to respect the integrity of the data types of my df
[image]

I transformed my df into a list, these are my data in the list:

[image]

this is the table where I want to insert my data:

[image]

This is the code:

```
sql_insert_temp = "INSERT INTO TEMPO('GIORNO','MESE','ANNO') VALUES(:2,:3,:4)"

index = 0
for i in df.iterrows():
   cursor.execute(sql_insert_temp,df_list[index])
   index += 1
connection.commit()
```

I have tried a single insert in the sqldeveloper worksheet, using the data you can see in the list, and it worked, so I guess I have made some mistake in the code. I have seen other discussions, but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.. Do you have any idea of how I can solve this or maybe is it possible to do this in another way?

I have tried to print the iterated queries and that's the result, that's why it's not inserting my data:

[image]

Comment: The  probable *root cause* - this is in Oracle *invalid* column name (quoted with apostrophs) `"INSERT INTO TEMPO('GIORNO','MESE','ANNO')` you should use *quotes* `'INSERT INTO TEMPO("GIORNO","MESE","ANNO")`.  Additionaly executemany would be better.

Comment: Apart from suggested `to_sql` method never use loop and insert, as it is very slow: too much roundtrips and parsing at every loop pass. Use [`executemany`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) with list of tuples to perform bulk insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a pandas DataFrame, then you should be able to use the `to_sql()` method provided by the pandas library.

```
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

DATABASE = 'DB'
SCHEMA   = 'DEV'
PASSWORD = 'password'
connection_string  = f'oracle://{SCHEMA}:{PASSWORD}@{DATABASE}'
db_conn     = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)

df_to_insert = df[['GIORNO', 'MESE', 'ANNO']] #creates a dataframe with only the columns you want to insert

df_to_insert.to_sql(name='TEMPO', con=db_connection, if_exists='append')
```

- name is the name of the table
- con is the connection object
- if_exists='append' will add the rows to end of the table. There are other options to add fail or drop and re-create the table

other parameters can be found on the pandas website. [pandas.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: now I am receving this error:
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number.


Is it possible I need to establish the connection with sqlalchemy?

Comment: Yup for Oracle is SQLAlchemy required, `Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. Legacy support is provided for sqlite3.Connection objects` see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: what module are you using to create your database connection?

Comment: @el_oso I am using cx_Oracle, but how can I use executemany without loop to insert everything? I am sorry guys if I am stubborn, it's the first time I use python to do such things ç_ç

Comment: No need for a loop. pandas module will automatically handle all rows in your dataframe. This can cause an issue with large DataFrames, so you can use the chunk size parameter to tell pandas to do the insert in batches of 50, 100, 1k rows at a time. Again, this is all handled in the background

Comment: Hello guys, I solved the troubles using executemany! Thank you so much everyone! You always help me a lot! °_°